# Android activity able to survive screen rotation but not minimizing

Tags: android, android-activity, serialization

Alright so i've got my app working so that when the screen orientation is changed it will store all of the important variable information in the `savedInstanceState` bundle, then it will read it back in upon creating the activity again with no problem.  This was a little tricky to do seeing as I am using an ArrayList of custom objects, so I implemented Serializable in my custom class.  This helped it work for the screen rotation, but when I click the home button or in anyway minimize the app, it crashes.

This is the error being thrown:

```
01-23 10:50:54.961  19756-19756/com.example.spencers.arcgisgeodb E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name = com.example.spencers.arcgisgeodb.agGDBFeatureTable)
            at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1285)
            at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1233)
            at android.os.Parcel.writeMapInternal(Parcel.java:591)
            at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1646)
            at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:605)
            at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.activityStopped(ActivityManagerNative.java:2318)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$StopInfo.run(ActivityThread.java:3100)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.esri.core.geodatabase.GeodatabaseFeatureTable
            at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1364)
            at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1671)
            at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1517)
            at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1481)
            at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFieldValues(ObjectOutputStream.java:979)
            at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:368)
            at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeHierarchy(ObjectOutputStream.java:1074)
            at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1404)
            at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1671)
            at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1517)
            at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1481)
            at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1280)
            at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1233)
            at android.os.Parcel.writeMapInternal(Parcel.java:591)
            at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1646)
            at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:605)
            at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.activityStopped(ActivityManagerNative.java:2318)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$StopInfo.run(ActivityThread.java:3100)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
```

The root problem seems to be this line:

> Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException:com.esri.core.geodatabase.GeodatabaseFeatureTable

That class is an external library that i'm using and is not editable.

part of my custom class that is being stored in the savedInstanceState bundle:

```
public class agGDBFeatureTable implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private GeodatabaseFeatureTable geodatabaseFeatureTable = null;
    private boolean active = true;
    private agLegendSymbol legendSymbols;
```

Here's my code for the onSaaveInstanceState method:

```
@Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        Log.i("Saved Instance", "onSaveInstanceState");
        for (int i = 0; i<gdbList.size(); i++) {
            savedInstanceState.putSerializable(i + "", gdbList.get(i));
        }
        savedInstanceState.putInt("NUMBEROFLAYERS",gdbList.size());
     }
```

**Now, my question is, why is it that my custom object can be serialized, stored in the bundle, and be restarted upon screen rotation, but when the app is minimized and it goes through the same process, it crashes and throws that error? And how can I fix it?**

Comment: is your class `GeodatabaseFeatureTable` is serializable?

Comment: No, the GeodatabaseFeatureTable is a class that I pull in from a library and it is not serializable, and it is not editable.

Comment: Subclass it,  and make that subclass serializable.

Comment: As in doing something like:
`public class GeodatabaseFeatureTable2 extends GeodatabaseFeatureTable implements Serializable`?

Not sure that that would work seeing as I never initialize the GeodatabaseFeatureTable object, I pull them from the Geodatabase file and use them from there.

The error it gives when I try that in the IDE is `No default constructor availiable in [class]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the fields of a class implementing Serializable must also be serializable. Clearly (by the exception), GeodatabaseFeatureTable is not. If a field is not serializable, it must be marked transient, like this:

```
private transient GeodatabaseFeatureTable geodatabaseFeatureTable = null;
```

This way you won't get an Exception. Now it's either ok for you that this object will not be persisted and be null again after deserialization, or you can do one of the following:

1. extend the GeodatabaseFeatureTable class and implement Serializable there, and use the extended class instead - note: of course, if the class is final, this is not an option
2. handle serializing that object right in your agGDBFeatureTable class by overriding the writeObject and readObject methods, and accessing relevant info from inside your GeodatabaseFeatureTable object - note: it may very well be that not everything you need will be accessible from the outside

I hope this helps. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your response,
   The first option won't be possible because it is a class from a library.  Could you tell me more about how to do the second option please?

Comment: If you google "java serialization writeObject example", you can find plenty of examples. The idea is that whenever Java serializes your object, it will call (your overridden version of) writeObject. In that method you can explicitly handle what to put and not to put in the serialized version. This has to be written along with readObject, which does the same in reverse. So, in effect, you could put there any primitive value that later helps to rebuild the state of your GeodatabaseFeatureTable object. As I don't know this class, I can't be more specific, but you get the idea.

Comment: As you say I could put any "primative" values in there but what i'm storing in there are other non-serializable objects and that's where my problems arise.

Comment: If they are your own classes, you can make them implement Serializable too, and then you are free to go using them in your top-level Serializable class as well.

Comment: They are not my own classes, they are custom classes.  My custom class contains a Geodatabase class which is a 3rd party class from ESRI.

Comment: Ok. What if you put the reference to the object in a Fragment and call setRetainInstance(true) on it? Your original problem was to survive orientation changes, this will surely do the job. See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html "Retaining an Object During a Configuration Change" section.